# How to cite organization's name with space between words

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I need to cite an article by the World Bank. However latex interpreted it as a person's name. My bib entry is

```
@book{wb,
    author={World Bank},
    year={1993},
    title={{The East Asian miracle: economic growth and public policy}},
    publisher={Oxford University Press},
    address={New York, N.Y},

    keywords={Economic conditions; Economic policy},
    isbn={0195209931, 9780195209938},
    language={English},}
```

And I get "Bank, W (1993)..." on my reference list. I used package `apacite` and `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. So I need something like "World Bank. (1993)..." (with the space between the words).
Any help is appreciated.
Cheers,
Long

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to protect the space:`World~Bank`

Comment: why not `{{World Bank}}`?

Comment: works like a charm. thanks @jlovegren. Normally I just put the title in double braces to keep the capital letters. Didn't know it works with author as well.

Comment: Can you please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? You might confuse `bibtex` with `biblatex`

Comment: @Martin I'm quite new to latex but I guess if you are referring to using a separate .bib file then yes I am using it. So all my references are stored in a file like mybib.bib and I called them with something like "\bibliography{mybib}".

Comment: Note that you really should write  title={The {East Asian} Miracle: Economic Growth and Public Policy} as this is much more flexible in terms of output. If you need normal capitalisation, use a bibliography style which does this rather than altering your database file.

Comment: I am referring to the way you handle your citations. Do you use the package [`\usepackage{biblatex}`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) or do you just use [bibtex](http://www.ctan.org/topic/bibtex-doc)? As far as I see, [apacite](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite) is a bibtex style. But you tagged you question biblatex.

Comment: @cfr - Since the entry is of type `@book`, no bibliography style I know of will try to convert to lower-case any of the  words in the `title` field. "Sentence style" -- which lower-cases all words except for the very first word of the `title` field -- is applied only to entries of type `@article`, `@misc`, `@techreport`, etc.

Comment: The Chicago styles used to do this but the current edition of the manual has changed this (in general - not just for books). I don't know of any others which do off hand, no. But it is still not a good solution to use lower case in the bib file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could put World Bank inside double brackets (`{{World Bank}}`). Like Mico points out in a comment, this will tell to BibTeX "to treat it as the name of a corporate author. None of the name's components will be parsed as being a first name, a "von" part, or a surname, and (importantly) sorting will be done by the first letter (here: W) of the field" (I am quoting Mico).

If you want more flexible and powerful settings, you should use BibLaTeX which has several mechanisms to treat corporate authors.

Comment: The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) has a whole section dedicated to *Corporate Authors and Editors* (§ 2.2.3) and is entirely OK with putting a corporate author or an organisation into the `author` or `editor` field, but of course advises to enclose the corporate name in curly braces such as `{World Bank}`. § 2.2.2, p. 20, states that `organization` takes "[t]he organization(s) that published a `@manual` or an `@online` resource, or sponsored a conference."

Comment: @moewe - The method of enclosing the name of a "corporate author" in double curly braces works with both BibTeX and biblatex. (I realize that you don't explicitly claim that the method works only with biblatex, but your write-up could be misunderstood that way.)